# Applying inverse transformation to a transformed image does not give original

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a Projective transformation `t`:

```
t = [0.646     0.110    9.339e-05;
     0.0113    0.551    -1.004e-05;
     307.649   1131.141         1]
```

When I apply  this transformation to an image and then apply the inverse of this transformation to the produced image, I was expecting to get back to the first image. But I am not!

```
tProj = projective2d(t);
img1 = imwarp(original,tProj);
figure(1); imshow(img1);

tProj2 = projective2d(inv(t));
img2 = imwarp(img1,tProj2);
figure(2); imshow(img2);
```

Original Image

[image: Original Image]

Transformation of original image

[image: Original Image]

Inverse transformation of transformation of original image

[image: Original Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close.  You must also reference the spatial location object (via a [`imref2d`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imref2d.html) object) to help capture the full spatial locations of the output image.  You specify this as an additional input into `imwarp` when inverting the image.  On top of this, you must also capture the output `imref2d` object from the from the first `imwarp` call.  Once you have these objects, you can use this to warp with the inverse to get the original image back.  Be advised that you will have some zero-padding due to the warped image extending beyond the dimensions of the original image.

In other words:

```
t = [0.646     0.110    9.339e-05;
0.0113    0.551    -1.004e-05;
307.649   1131.141         1];

original = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZzdT.jpg');

tProj = projective2d(t);
[img1, ra] = imwarp(original, tProj); % New
figure(1); imshow(img1);

tProj2 = projective2d(inv(t));
img2 = imwarp(img1,ra,tProj2); % New
figure(2); imshow(img2);
```

This is the output image I get after inverting the warped image:

[image]